# Unable to create bundleRelease with Reactnative

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, apk

I am able to get the React-Native application working on Emulator for Android, however I can not create the release bundle. When I run the command './gradlew bundleRelease', I get the following error.

> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @58b03248

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:207)
  ........
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @58b03248
  at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.UnsafeReflectionAccessor.makeAccessible(UnsafeReflectionAccessor.java:44)

Any help would be appreciated as stuck so long here!

Comment: I am facing the same issue?... any breakthrough in this?